# List is not updating - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I've saw a code snippet for my app that i wanted to usw.. my problem now is that when i'm typing a new task into the app, my app just won't show that to the screen until a hot reload of the app. But first the user can't do any hot reloads AND for user experience it's very bad. If you need more code or debug things, please ask in the comments!

Here i the code (Ig it's this part thats not updating):

tasks_data.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:learnon/models/task.dart';
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

int id = 0;
List<Task> _taskList = [];

class TaskData extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<String>? task = [];
  List<String>? boxValue = [];
  List<String>? dates = [];
  List<String>? uid = [];
  Future getData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //prefs.clear();
    task!.clear();
    boxValue!.clear();
    _taskList.clear();
    task = prefs.getStringList("task");
    boxValue = prefs.getStringList("check");
    dates = prefs.getStringList("date");
    uid = prefs.getStringList("id");
    if (task == null) {
      task = ["Long Press to clear tasks"];
      boxValue = ["false"];
      dates = ["2021-05-24 02:18:04Z"];
      uid = [id.toString()];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < boxValue!.length; i++) {
      _taskList.add(Task(
          name: task![i],
          isDone: boxValue![i] == 'true',
          date: DateTime.parse(dates![i]),
          id: int.parse(uid![i])));
    }
    id = int.parse(uid!.last);
    id += 2;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    task!.clear();
    boxValue!.clear();
    dates!.clear();
    uid!.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < _taskList.length; i++) {
      task!.add(_taskList[i].name!);
      boxValue!.add(_taskList[i].isDone.toString());
      dates!.add(_taskList[i].date.toString());
      uid!.add(_taskList[i].id.toString());
    }
    await prefs.setStringList("task", task!);
    await prefs.setStringList("check", boxValue!);
    await prefs.setStringList("date", dates!);
    await prefs.setStringList("id", uid!);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  UnmodifiableListView<Task> get tasks {
    return UnmodifiableListView(_taskList);
  }

  void addTask(String t, DateTime d, int uid) {
    _taskList.add(Task(name: t, date: d, id: uid));
    setData();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int get taskCount {
    return _taskList.length;
  }

  void updateTask(Task task) {
    task.toggleDone();
    setData();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteTask(Task t) {
    _taskList.remove(t);
    setData();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

tasksscreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:learnon/widgets/tasks_list.dart';
import 'package:learnon/screens/add_task_screen.dart';
import 'package:learnon/models/tasks_data.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

import '../widgets/app_drawer.dart';

bool theme = false;
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

class TasksScreenNew extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = "/tasksnew";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<TaskData>(
        create: (_) => TaskData(),
        builder: (context, __) => Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Tasks"),
                centerTitle: true,
              ),
              drawer: AppDrawer(),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: null,
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                      isScrollControlled: true,
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => AddTaskScreen());
                },
              ),
              body: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 60, left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Builder(
                            builder: (context) => FloatingActionButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.refresh,
                                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                size: 30,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Tasks',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 50,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '${Provider.of<TaskData>(context).taskCount} Task(s) übrig',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        child: TasksList(),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    )
                  ]),
            ));
  }
}
// CircleAvatar(
// radius: 30,
// backgroundColor: Colors.white,
// child: Icon(
// Icons.list,
// color: Colors.blueAccent,
// size: 30,
// ),
// )
```

tasks_list.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:learnon/screens/tasksscreennew.dart';
import 'package:learnon/widgets/task_tile.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:learnon/models/tasks_data.dart';
import 'dart:core';

class TasksList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TasksList> createState() => _TasksListState();
}

class _TasksListState extends State<TasksList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TaskData>(
      builder: (context, taskData, child) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return TaskTile(
              taskTitle: taskData.tasks[index].name,
              isChecked: taskData.tasks[index].isDone,
              timeLeft: taskData.tasks[index].date!
                          .difference(DateTime.now())
                          .inMinutes >
                      0
                  ? ('${taskData.tasks[index].date!.difference(DateTime.now()).inHours.toString()} Hours left')
                  : 'Time Expired',
              checkboxCallback: (checkBoxState) {
                taskData.updateTask(taskData.tasks[index]);
              },
              longPressCallback: () {
                if ((taskData.tasks[index].id!) != 0 ||
                    (taskData.tasks[index].id!) != 1) {
                  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
                      .cancel(taskData.tasks[index].id!);
                  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
                      .cancel(taskData.tasks[index].id! + 1);
                }
                taskData.deleteTask(taskData.tasks[index]);
              },
              notificationCallback: () {
                flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
                    .cancel(taskData.tasks[index].id!);
                flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
                    .cancel(taskData.tasks[index].id! + 1);
              },
            );
          },
          itemCount: taskData.taskCount,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

task_tile.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TaskTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool? isChecked;
  final String? taskTitle;
  final Function? checkboxCallback;
  final Function longPressCallback;
  final Function notificationCallback;
  final String? timeLeft;
  TaskTile(
      {this.isChecked = false,
      this.taskTitle,
      this.checkboxCallback,
      required this.longPressCallback,
      this.timeLeft,
      required this.notificationCallback()});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onLongPress: () {
        longPressCallback();
      },
      title: Text(
        taskTitle!,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          color: (timeLeft!) == 'Time Expired'
              ? Colors.red
              : isChecked!
                  ? Colors.green
                  : null,
        ),
      ),
      subtitle: Text(
        isChecked! ? 'Completed' : (timeLeft!),
        style: TextStyle(
          color: (timeLeft!) == 'Time Expired'
              ? Colors.red
              : isChecked!
                  ? Colors.green
                  : null,
        ),
      ),
      trailing: Checkbox(
        activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: (value) {
          if (value == true) {
            notificationCallback();
          }
          checkboxCallback!(value);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

addtaskscreen.dart

```
// ignore_for_file: deprecated_member_use

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:learnon/models/tasks_data.dart';
import 'package:date_field/date_field.dart';
import 'package:learnon/screens/tasksscreennew.dart';

import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

String? newTaskTitle;
DateTime? dateTime;

class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<TaskData>(
        create: (_) => TaskData(),
        builder: (context, __) => Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 300,
              color: Colors.black,
              child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 300,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 50, vertical: 30),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Task hinzufügen',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          // controller: myController,
                          autofocus: true,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            newTaskTitle = value;
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Abgabedatum',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        DateTimeFormField(
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: null),
                            errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.event_note),
                          ),
                          mode: DateTimeFieldPickerMode.dateAndTime,
                          initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
                          firstDate: DateTime.now(),
                          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                          validator: (e) => (e?.day ?? 0) == 1
                              ? 'Please not the first day'
                              : null,
                          onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
                            dateTime = value;
                          },
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
                          ),
                          autofocus: false,
                          onPressed: () async {
                            print(newTaskTitle);
                            print(dateTime);
                            Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false)
                                .addTask(newTaskTitle!, dateTime!, id);
                            await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
                              id++,
                              'Zeit abgelaufen',
                              newTaskTitle!,
                              dateTime!,
                              const NotificationDetails(
                                  android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                                      '1', 'Zeit abgelaufen')),
                              androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
                            );
                            await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
                              id++,
                              dateTime!.difference(DateTime.now()).inMinutes /
                                          2 <
                                      60
                                  ? '${dateTime!.difference(DateTime.now()).inMinutes / 2} Minuten übrig'
                                  : '${dateTime!.difference(DateTime.now()).inHours / 2} Stunden übrig',
                              newTaskTitle!,
                              dateTime!.subtract(Duration(
                                  minutes: dateTime!
                                          .difference(DateTime.now())
                                          .inMinutes ~/
                                      2)),
                              const NotificationDetails(
                                  android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                                      '5', 'Reminder')),
                              androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
                            );
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            'Hinzufügen',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              // backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                    ),
                  )),
            ));
  }
}
```

Comment: actually brother you doing it wrong you make the _tasklist a gloabl variable to listen that change yo have to wrap this inside valuenotifier and list than changes through value notifier builder

Comment: @AliHassan could you please make an Answer with the code detached? This would be really nice!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're making your **TaskData** as a **ChangeNotifier, are you wrapping your widget inside a **Consumer** widget, and using this class inside the **Consumer** widget, like this:

```
Consumer<TaskData>(
  builder: (context, taskData, child) {
    return <YOUR_WIDGET_HERE>;
  }
)
```

That way all changes you make via your service class should be reflected and trigger a rebuild on your widget?

Also are you using a MultiProvider widget, how are you providing this class?

Comment: could you post the whole code with this fix included? i don't know where i should put this in my code... i'm kinda new to flutter, sorry

Comment: No worries. The thing is that you are not showing your widgets here; this is only the logic to render the widgets or like the business logic. Please share some of the widget logic, that way we can show you were to place it.

Comment: Ah sure. I will edit the code above. But it's alot of code tho... hang on

Comment: now, every piece of the code is included :)

Comment: One thing to point out is that you're adding two **ChangeNotifierProvider** - one in the **AddTaskScreen** and in the **TaskScreenNew** - you should "lift the state" so both of these can access it from a parent, so you could use a **MultiProvider** around your main app (maybe inside runApp). I noticed you already had a **Consumer** widget in the **TasksList** so that should work once you call **notifyListeners** on your **TaskData**. Also make sure you have all properties encapsulated inside your provider service (int id = 0;
List<Task> _taskList = []). Try cleaning these up and see.

Comment: That wasn't the solution... i've made the stateless widgets to stateful one's and added the multiprovider taskdata in main.dart

Comment: True, that was not the solution - i didn't have enough space to say that (sorry!) - I only wanted to point out that you could've added a MultiProvider, now you did so that's good. Now I'm curious because the code looks straightforward. Would love to run it on my end.